# Group SELECT request using same attribute name

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to merge two `SELECT` request and group it into the same attributes.

I have two tables which contain lot of attributes and some are in common (or have the same meaning in "human language").

I already tried the `CROSS JOIN` and the `SELECT * FROM table1 (SELECT * FROM TABLE2))` but it won't work.

For example:

Table1:

```
{[Attribute1 = "Name1", 
 Attribute2 = age1, 
 Attribute3 = "Bla", 
 Attribute4 = "Blabla",  
 Attribute5 = 153, 
 Attribute6 = "something"] , 
 [Attribute1=....,....], ...}
```

Table2:

```
{[Attribute1="Name25", 
 NotInterestingAttribute1="blabla", 
 Attribute15=125, 
 Attribute18="somethingElse"], 
 [Attribute1=....], ...}
```

My aim is to obtain something like

FinalTable:

```
{[Attribute1="Name1", Attribute2=125, Attribute3="something"] , 
 [Attribute1="Name25", Attribute2=153, Attribute3="somethingElse"]}
```

*I'm really sorry, I tried to make some real table but I failed.*

I don't know if I'm clear enough, please let me know if I'm not.

Thanks for the help !

EDIT:

This is the SELECT request I'm trying to use at the moment:

```
SELECT Attribute1 as Attribute1, 
       Attribute5 as Attribute2, 
       Attribute15 as Attribute2, 
       Attribute6 as Attribute3, 
       Attribute18 as Attribute3 
FROM   Table1, Table2 
WHERE  Attribute1 like '%name%';
```

Comment: How do you get this output ?

Comment: I created it just to show an example. 

The tables I work with are very large and contains some confidential informations that I should not put on the Internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT Attribute1 as Attribute1, Attribute5 as Attribute2, Attribute15 as Attribute2, Attribute6 as Attribute3, Attribute18 as Attribute3 
FROM Table1
WHERE Attribute1 like '%name%'
UNION ALL
SELECT Attribute1 as Attribute1, Attribute5 as Attribute2, Attribute15 as Attribute2, Attribute6 as Attribute3, Attribute18 as Attribute3 
FROM Table2
WHERE Attribute1 like '%name%'
```

But if the field are name different on each table you use alias so they are align on the same field

```
SELECT Attribute1 as Attribute1, Attribute5 as Attribute2, Attribute6 as Attribute3
FROM Table1
WHERE Attribute1 like '%name%'
UNION ALL
SELECT Attribute1 as Attribute1, Attribute15 as Attribute2, Attribute18 as Attribute3 
FROM Table2
WHERE Attribute1 like '%name%'
```

Comment: I am indeed !

I tried quickly but it shows a "No database selected" error.

Maybe I did it wrong, I will try it tomorrow with MySQL doc. Thank you so much !

Comment: well that looks like you arent connected to the db. But that is a different issue.

Comment: I read again and looks like you are trying to match columns but they are named differently. In that case you align those like my edit.

Comment: It was perfect. I don't know why but I had to add the db_name before the table name after the FROM (whereas it worked without it for others request).

Thanks again